# What is right way to build database with deep dependencies in Django?

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models

For expample I have something like this: User->Company->Worker->SomeStuff->SomeDeeperStuff
Straight way looks like:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
class Worker(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

and so on... And this is looks like right way for me.
But some times i want to make a shortcut and add ForeignKey(User) to all other models (Worker, SomeStuff...).
So what is the Right way? The Zen path? And if my straight way is best, what is best way to filter content for users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) is not the right way but can be used if you have performance problems.  Do you have a large amount of data and you joined queries are slow?

The best way to get user's data is the standard join:

```
SomeDeeperStuff.objects.filter(somestuff__worker__company__user=user)
```

Comment: No perfomance problems yet. I missed this __some__stuff__ construction.